# php connect mysql database via mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I try to connect to a mysql database via PHPs mysqli.

```
define('DB_SERVER', '127.0.0.3');
define('DB_USERNAME', '570466');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pssst!');
define('DB_NAME', 'db570466');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
```

And get the following error:
`Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user '570466'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /.../config.php on line 16`

The strange thing is, that Access is denied for my user `@localhost`, but I don't connect to localhost. According to my hoster (domainFactory), I can also connect to the DB via `mysql5.my-domain.tld`, but that gives me the same output.

What am I missing?

Comment: A) Are you connecting to the right database server? B) Are you sure you're authorized with those exact credentials? C) Is that the correct database name?

Comment: Just a side note, I would advise against posting usernames, passwords, or API keys in your questions, regardless of whether or not the server is local.

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, just a clarification: that mention of `localhost` in the error message does not refer to the host you are connecting *to*, it is the host your MySQL server thinks you are connecting *from* after resolving your IP.

Comment: @tadman A) Yes. I asked my hoster how to connect to the database and they gave me these two options. B) I'm pretty sure they are correct, I checked them at least 10 times C) Yes, at least the support didn't tell me anything else

RussJ: Good point, actually that aren't my real credentials (except the host-url)

rickdenhaan: Oh, thats a good hint! So do you think providing the port explicitly could help?

Ben Garb: I don't know my hosters architecture, so I can't tell if the Web- and DB-Servers are running on the same machine or not, but my php files are hosted on their webserver

Comment: As a note, `127.0.0.3` is one *strange* way to connect to your database server. This is normally `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Adding the port won't help, the server is responding fine so it's using the correct port. Are you 100% sure you're using the correct username and password? According to the [DomainFactory help pages](https://www.df.eu/int/support/df-faq/webhosting/datenbanken/mysql-datenbanken/#c1404) the username is supposed to start with "db".

Comment: @rickdenhaan ohhhhhhh, THAT'S what I was missing. Thanks alot! Do you want to post your suggestion as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the help pages](https://www.df.eu/int/support/df-faq/webhosting/datenbanken/mysql-datenbanken/#c1404), database usernames for DomainFactory should start with "db":

> Den Usernamen Ihrer Datenbank sehen Sie im Kundenmenü unter "MySQL-Datenbanken". Er hat das Format db12345 bzw. db12345_1 bei weiteren Datenbanken.

(translated:)

> The username for your database can be found in the customer portal under "MySQL databases". It has the format db12345 or db12345_1 for subsequent databases.

So you should be able to connect to the database "db570466" using the username `db570466` instead of just `570466`.

Answer (score -2):

You are using 127.0.0.3, but it is rejecting "localhost". So use "localhost" instead. And be sure the user 570766@localhost has permission.